# my script wont work for windows service recovery

Tags: windows, windows-services

I can seem to get this setting to work.

[image]

My `asfh.vbs` looks like this:

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("iexplore")
Set objShell = Nothing
```

I crash my app by letting an exception go unhandled i know this works because if i change the recovery setting First Failure to "Restart the service", it works.

My settings for "Log on" are Local System account.

The script works if i use it in the command prompt (cmd.exe) with this command:

`wscript.exe "C:\asfh.vbs"`

So is it the Local System account that stops me or should this be possible to do?

**EDIT**

Working script, thanks to Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007

```
Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' How to write file
outFile="c:\test.inf"
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
objFile.Write "test string" & vbCrLf
objFile.Close
```

Comment: Try specifying the full path to wscript.exe. Also, a desktop shell won't exist for that service user, so your script may be running, but failing to do what you expect (open IE). Perhaps try it with a script that write a log file to disk, or an event to the event log to confirm if it's running or not?

Comment: Thank you, i'll try that. ultimately i would like to run annother exe (console app) i wrote myself to email our office to let us know the service has failed. but thats the next step then i guess :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thank you! you were right, look at my edit for the working example. you can make an answer if you want so i can accept. or can i mark an comment as the right answer?